# Update A Firebase node with a Snapshot data without overwriting Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking at synching a node e.g. /a/b/c with node /data/c

There is data at node /a/b/c - so I just want to grab a snapshot of /data/c and put that data in to /a/b/c without deleting existing values.

Would an approach like :

```
Ref.update({
                                snapshotdata.val()
                            }).key;
```

Would this work? I'm not sure how firebase would parse the snapshot, if it takes the whole thing and overwrites or it would take individual values and adds.

Thanks in advance for any clarity.

Best Regards,
Kieran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Snapshot values are simply JSON objects (or primitives, depending on the node). `update()` will replace any nodes specified by the keys in the update, but not any that aren't. So if `/a/b/c` looks like:

```
{
  name: 'old name',
  data: {
    gonnabe: 'gone'
  },
  created: 12345679
}
```

and `data/c` looks like:

```
{
  name: 'new name',
  data: {
    nested: true
  },
  updated: 12345679
}
```

doing an `db.ref('a/b/c').update(dataSnapshot.val())` will result in:

```
{
  name: 'new name',
  data: {
    nested: true
  },
  created: 12345679,
  updated: 12345679
}
```

Note that the nested field in `data` was wiped out by the update, but the non-nested field `created` was not.

If you want to do deep updates, you'll need to construct an update with slash-delimited fields for each deep node you want to update. So instead of the above, you might have:

```
{
  "name": "new name",
  "data/nested": true,
  "updated" 12345679
}
```

This will be non-destructive to the nested data and only update values that are directly referenced, resulting in:

```
{
  name: 'new name',
  data: {
    gonnabe: 'gone',
    nested: true
  },
  created: 12345679,
  updated: 12345679
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great answer thank you! Well laid out and explained.

Comment: Actually one question on the above; Am I right in assuming that for unique values in the snapshot, it won't destructively update the existing node? e.g. /a/b/c { tokens { a : 1, b :2 }  ---- /z/data/tokens {c : 15 }

Comment: Correct, the update will only overwrite nodes that are specified in the data passed to `update()` so in your example, `c` would not overwrite `tokens`.

Comment: Great thanks. My problem is that I'm trying to copy, potentially thousands of nodes from 1-5 nodes to a node (to prep push notifications). Looping through it to add them is safer though is much slower. So I'm trying to figure out a way that isn't destructive and is fast.